# Install "Ifcopenshell" in google-colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory, ifc-open-shell

I've tried with: **import ifcopenshell**

after that I tried: **!pip install -q ifcopenshell**

and later with : **!apt-get -qq install -y ifcopenshell**

I had an error in all three cases: **Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ifcopenshell (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for ifcopenshell**

... How can I install "ifcopenshell" in google-colaboratory ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use conda

```
!wget -c https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!conda install -c conda-forge -c oce -c dlr-sc -c ifcopenshell ifcopenshell

import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe we must leave as linux, as we are cloning a repo inside google colab.
Just open a notebook in googlecollab, copy and paste the exact lines previewsly suggested, and run.